# AngularJS: Updating table contents from Select option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, html-select, single-page-application

Currently, I am trying to get more acquainted with AngularJS and single page applications. I feel like I am making some headway, which I find empowering, since I found WPF relatively confusing.

However, I feel like I am having a grave misunderstanding of what AngularJS is supposed to do. To frame my question more simply, I have constructed a basic example website so that I can practice.

The website is formatted like a menu for soda products where the user can select different vendors, and then the available sizes to view the price of the product. This is simply for example and the prices and sizes (IE, data displayed on the web page) not meant to be correct. What is meant to be correct is my method and format for displaying such information.

My problem is that I cannot seem to access the scope's "selectedVendor" ng-model from my template URL (or at least not "traditionally" I.E., by simply typing the name). This breaks my code as I need to get the list of available sizes from what vendor has been selected.

I looked through several other similar questions, but the answers provided all seemed to point to the ng-repeat option being the offending party. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Menu - Beverages</title>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="routerApp">
        <div id="main">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']).run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state){$rootScope.$state = $state;}]);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')
    $stateProvider

    .state('home',{
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'beverages_home.html',
        controller: 'beveragesController'
    })
})
routerApp.controller('beveragesController', function($scope){
    $scope.vendors=[
        {
            Name: 'Pepsi-Cola',
            Sizes:{
                Small:{
                    Size:'8oz',
                    Price:'0.50'
                },
                Medium:{
                    Size:'16oz',
                    Price:'1.50'
                },
                Large:{
                    Size:'24oz',
                    Price:'2.50'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            Name: 'Coke',
            Sizes:{
                Small:{
                    Size:'Teaspoon',
                    Price:'4.50'
                },
                Medium:{
                    Size:'Tablespoon',
                    Price:'8.50'
                },
                Large:{
                    Size:'Quart',
                    Price:'25.50'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            Name: 'A&W',
            Sizes:{
                Small:{
                    Size:'Half Gallon',
                    Price:'0.25'
                },
                Medium:{
                    Size:'1 Liter',
                    Price:'1.00'
                },
                Large:{
                    Size:'2 Liter',
                    Price:'1.25'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    $scope.units=[ 'Dollars', 'Euro', 'Yen'
    ]
})
```

beverages_home.html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Vendor</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select ng-model="selectedVendor" ng-options="vendor as vendor.Name for vendor in vendors" ng-init="selectedVendor = vendors[0]"></select></td>
        <td><select ng-model="selectedSize" ng-options="size as size.Size for size in selectedVendor.Sizes" ng-init="selectedSize = vendors[0].Sizes[0]"></select></td>
        <td><select ng-model="selectedUnits" ng-options="unit for unit in units" ng-init="selectedUnits = units[0]"></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{selectedVendor.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{selectedSize.Size}}</td>
        <td>{{selectedSize.Price}} {{selectedUnits}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Currently, I have my web page able to select between vendors and price units. However, I am not able to see or select a size, and because of that the price field is never filled. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? I don't care if I have to restructure anything, I would just like to learn this the correct way, or the cleanest way that lends to the most organization and scalability.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not. Should I? I thought that the controller directive was specified in the .state('home',{
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'beverages_home.html',
        controller: 'beveragesController'
    })

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to the carriage return in the comments section submitting the comment. My bad!

Comment: yes. I see now that you have it in the route. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: I will give the angular styleguide a look, thanks!

Comment: Not a solution, but in order to learn the 'cleanest way' I recommend to have a look on the [angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md). Especially you should avoid to access the [$scope directly](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controlleras-controller-syntax) and reduce [nested code](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#named-vs-anonymous-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problems comes because Sizes is not an arry but rather an object, an therefore you cannot access the way you are trying. Try with an array of sizes instead!

Comment: i.e.  Sizes:[
                Small:{
                    Size:'8oz',
                    Price:'0.50'
                },
                Medium:{
                    Size:'16oz',
                    Price:'1.50'
                },
                Large:{
                    Size:'24oz',
                    Price:'2.50'
                }
            ]

Comment: This worked for me. Having just started learning JS and angular I thought that I could iterate through a container object's properties, but this solution makes it evident why that would not be the case and where my shortfalls were. I actually thought I was making an array, looks like I have plenty of reading ahead of me. Thanks a bunch!